# Ionic 4 - Inappbrowser failed to load in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

I am working on project where we need to get a JWT token from a external source to the mobile app. In Android it works without any issue. However in IOS i am not able to get the token from the Iframe.

I have used both Ionic and Cordova inappbrowsers, the authentication works fine and i am able to execute script inside the iframe in IOS, but while using the callback function in executescript() function, gap-iab:// was blocked by content security policy.

Did anyone faced a issue like this in IOS and solved it. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

My Code:

```
const bro = this.iab.create(legacyUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
bro.on('loadstop').subscribe( (e) => {
                bro.executeScript({
                  code: 'if (document.getElementById("Token") != null) { document.getElementById("Token"). 
                         getAttribute("value");}'
                }).then((value) => {
                   console.log(value);
                });
});
```

And i am getting below error from the application while running in IOS simulator,

```
Refused to load gap-iab://InAppBrowser627412330/%5Bnull%5D because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

Answer (score 0):

"gap-iab:" needs to be child-src in your content security policy. That is usually set on your server side and tells your in-app-browser which content it can load and from where.